# retrieve values of rows (from Postgresql) in a list in java

Tags: java, postgresql, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap

I Used a HashMap for handling my ResultSet queried from PostgreSql using the code suggested by [RHT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507121/efficient-way-to-handle-resultset-in-java)

```
public List resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(50);

    while (rs.next()){
        HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
        for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){           
            row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
    }

    return list;
}
```

I did it beacuse I wanted to shuffle this collection afterwards.

now each row is like that:

```
  {owner=22172613@N07, count=2}
```

I do not know how I can do a for/each loop that I retrieve each owner id and corresponding number !!

Comment: Can you post your table structure?  You might not need to call `getObject`.

Comment: Don't use raw types but use interfaces for collections! `Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>(columns)`. After that, examine if you really need to put an `java.lang.Object` into your map or if you may have some other datatype...

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen   what I get as result set is the list of my users and the number of images that each have in my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have an `ArrayList` each element of which is a `HashMap` that contains in its key the column names of the results and in its values the values of those columns.

A loop that will most probably help you is the following:

```
    //call your method resultSetToArrayList here
     List<Map> list = (List<Map>) resultSetToArrayList(rs);

    //loop the list
    for(Map r: list) {
        System.out.println("row data: ");
        final Iterator columnIterator = r.keySet().iterator();
        while(columnIterator.hasNext()) {
            final Object next = columnIterator.next();
            System.out.println("\tColumn: " + next + " / Value: " + r.get(next));
        }
    }
```

Comment: but still it is not possible to compare it with string
` if (next.toString() == "owner") {
                    printDebug(next +""+userImages.get(next) );
                    owner = userImages.get(next).toString();
                }`

Comment: that's another problem not mentioned in your initial question. You asked for a loop to retrieve the values, well here it is, expand it more to do what you want. Can you post what the loop prints?

Comment: the problem was I used `if (next =="owner")` but the correct version is `next.equals("owner")`

Comment: I just realized that with this solution some of the key values are missing!
do you know why it's happening!

Comment: it was just because of forgetting closing the buffer for writer!