# Java - NULL ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have a function to fetch data from MySQL table

```
public ResultSet getAddressID(String city) throws SQLException{
        String q = "SELECT PK_ADDRESS_ID FROM tbl_addresses WHERE city =" + "\""+ city+ "\";";
        ResultSet rs = executeSearch(q);
        return rs;
    }
```

When I try `System.out.println(n.getAddressID("Sheffield"));` it returns `null`. Why this happened even though there are data in my table (see picture).

[image]

```
public ResultSet executeSearch(String q){
    openConnection();
    try{
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(q);
        closeConnection();
        return resultSet;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        closeConnection();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the `executeSearch` method .

Comment: Updated `executeSearch` method.

Comment: Don't `finally` blocks get executed no matter what? Not sure, with Java, but it seems wrong to return from a finally block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your executeSearch method; the `finally` block will always execute, so by returning null in the finally block, you essentially *override* what you returned in the try block!

This could be an alternative solution; note that I'm returning at the end of the method instead of within any parts of the try-catch-finally block.

```
/**
 * Converts a provided ResultSet into a generic List so that the
 * ResultSet can be closed while the data persists.
 * Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7507225/899126
 */
public List convertResultSetToList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    List list = new ArrayList(50);

    while (rs.next())
    {
        HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
        for(int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i)
        {
            row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
    }

    return list;
}

public List executeSearch(String q)
{
    List toReturn;
    openConnection();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        toReturn = this.convertResultSetToList(statement.executeQuery(q));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        toReturn = new ArrayList();
    }
    finally {
        closeConnection();
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I try to fetch the first element of `ResultSet` and print it out. Here's the code 
`if (rs.next()){
      i = rs.getInt(1);
     };`. Somehow I getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`

Comment: Your version works btw. But it just returns a single line `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@21b8d17c`

Comment: That's because closing the database connection also closes related ResultSets. I've updated my answer to include a method borrowed heavily from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7507225/899126; essentially, you'd convert the ResultSet to a list of HashMaps.